# Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement

Tags: homebrew, big-sur

I started getting warnings like these today on running `brew upgrade` or `brew cleanup`:

```
Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the stelligent/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/stelligent/homebrew-tap/Formula/config-lint.rb:6

Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the instrumenta/instrumenta tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/instrumenta/homebrew-instrumenta/Formula/kubeval.rb:6
```

What do they mean and how to fix them?

Comment: You're using custom homebrew formula taps that are giving obsolete arguments (`:unneeded`) to homebrew.  As the message says, if you want to rid yourself of the warning, you should contact the maintainers of `stelligent/tap` (possibly: https://github.com/stelligent/homebrew-tap) and `instrumenta/instrumenta` and tell them to update their formulas.

Comment: Fair enough. Apparently, one can also remove the taps that are not needed anymore with `brew untap <tapname>`.

Comment: Related question for reference: homebrew - What does 'bottle :unneeded' do? - Stack Overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45163490

Comment: Maybe a better place to ask homebrew related question is here: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions

Answer (score 2):

Just `brew untap stelligent/tap` and `brew untap instrumenta/instrumenta` and whatever caused the problem, if it told you some package was installed by the tap and refused to untap, just `brew uninstall (the package it told you)` and then `brew untap` it again.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew itself might need to be updated: `brew update`

Comment: I've run it, doesn't seem to fix the warnings.